# difficulty with abstract algebra lemma implying FT of finite abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I'm having some difficulty following the below proof.

[image: lemma]
[image: proof]

I understand everything up to the last three lines; I specifically don't understand how they're concluding that the intersection of the subgroup generated by $gH$ and $K/H$ is equal to $\{H\}$, or in different terms the identity element in $G/H$. Moreover I'm not sure how they arrive at the conclusion that the internal product of $k$ & the group generated by $g$ is equal to $G$, though I think it has to do with the isomorphism theorems?

If anyone could spell out what steps I'm implicitly missing here I'd very much appreciate it, since I've been stuck on it for the last hours.

Thank you!

Comment: You are working by induction. The induction is that if you have an abelian group $A$ of order $p^k$, with $k\lt n$ ($|G|=p^n$), and $a\in A$ has maximal possible order, then you can find a subgroup $B$ of $A$ such that $A=\langle a\rangle\times B$. At that point in the proof, you have concluded that $G/H$ has order $p^{m-1}$, and that the element $gH$ in $G/H$ has maximal possible order. By the induction hypothesis, there is a subgroup $B$ of $G/H$ such that $G/H=\langle gH\rangle\times B$; in particular, $\langle gH\rangle \cap B = \{eH\}$, the identity element of $G/H$.  (cont)

Comment: The correspondence Theorem tells you that *every* subgroup of $G/H$ is of the form $K/H$, where $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ that contains $H$. Thus, $B=K/H$ for some $K$. So, $G/H = \langle gH\rangle \times (K/H)$, and the fact that the intersection is $\{H\}$ is because you have a direct product decomposition. The claim is that we can "lift" this to show $G=\langle g\rangle\times K$. You have that $|K|=|K/H||H| = p|K/H|$, and $|K/H|=p^{(n-1)-m}$, so $|K|=p^{n-m}$. Once you have $G=\langle g\rangle K$, order considerations force $K\cap\langle g\rangle=\{e\}$.